# Left Join with only one of multiple matches in the right table

Tags: mysql, join, select, mysql-8.0, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database, where every entry may have multiple names, therefore I made a name database. While all names will be displayed otherwhere I need a list of all main entries with one representative name. All names are ranked and the one with the highest ranking-position shall be used. Unranked names are “0” or “-1” and should be ignored and since the name-ranking-system is bad, the one to use is not always “1”. In the case of no name being there, the main entry should still be returned.

In short: I need a left join that takes all entries of table “main” and joins them with the name that has the smallest, greater than 0, position, if there is one.

main:

```
| main_ID | val_A | val_B |
+---------+-------+-------+
|       2 | some  | stuff |
|       3 | and   | more  |
|       4 | even  | more  |
```

names:

```
| name_ID | main_ID | name           | position |
+---------+---------+----------------+----------+
|       1 |       2 | best name      |        1 |
|       2 |       2 | some name      |        0 |
|       3 |       3 | alt name       |        3 |
|       4 |       2 | cool name      |        2 |
|       5 |       3 | abandoned name |       -1 |
|       6 |       3 | awesome name   |        2 |
```

what I want to get:

```
| main_ID | val_A | val_B | name         |
+---------+-------+-------+--------------+
|       2 | some  | stuff | best name    |
|       3 | and   | more  | awesome name |
|       4 | even  | more  |              |
```

Comment: See the tag added

Comment: which mysql version? Part of the Structured Query Language is to have data with specific meanings and many meanings. Is cleaning up this data acceptable?

Comment: I am using version 8.0.33. Cleaning or restructuring would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

set sql_mode='';
select * from (select t1.* from names t1, names t2 where t1.main_id=t2.main_id and t1.position<t2.position and t1.position>0)t  group by main_id;

Use this query  you can get the minimal and positive position row for eatch main_id, and then you can use a left join  from table "main" as a outer query.